# Subscribing to url in python/ros (axis_camera)

Tags: python, camera, ros, ethernet

I do not fully understand the following Python / ROS [code](https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera/tree/7722fe64d304695548129af44e4c222160cbb787). There, images are read from ethernet connected camera and are published with ROS. The code works perfectly fine, but I do not understand the following two lines:

1.) [peer_subscribe()](https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera/blob/7722fe64d304695548129af44e4c222160cbb787/nodes/axis.py#L170): When is this function peer_subscribe() activated? It has to run continuously at the rate of the published image?

2.) [StreamThread.start()](https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera/blob/7722fe64d304695548129af44e4c222160cbb787/nodes/axis.py#L174) I cannot find this function? Where is it defined?

Maybe someone knows this repo and can help me.

It is not an issue, therefore I don't want to ask this question on github/issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you at 2.) the `start()` method calls the run method of the StreamThread class. In this case the following method:

```
def run(self):
    while(True):
        self.stream()
```

For 1.) the function `peer_subscribe(...)` is called everytime a node subscribes to the topic. In this case the function is called if a node subscribes the camera data and then the Stream starts publishing wihtin its thread.

Comment: Thanks! 2.) Why is `start()` calling `run()`? How does it know `run()` = `start()`? 1.) Is there a documentation to `peer_subscribe()`? Is it a special ROS attribute?

Comment: 1. See https://docs.ros.org/en/api/mir_driver/html/classmir__bridge_1_1PublisherWrapper.html#a37e13201bacd0a625e5598a8d30e34e1 . I think its an own implemented class .  2.) Its the core implementation of a thread. If you call start on a thread always the run method is executed and passed in an own process.